# Laravel: Cannot access empty property for array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am making axios post to an endpoint I have with an array of objects:

`dataTargets = [{target: "page:455880961418394", stream_url: "fds", stream_key: "sdf"}, {target: "page:f334234", stream_url: "test", stream_key: "test1"}]`

```
axios.post('/admin/finish-live', {
   copy_urls: dataTargets
});
```

I've logged `dataTargets` right before the post call is made to ensure it's there.

My controller on the backend is trying to grab these, `$request->copy_urls`, but I'm getting the error `Cannot access empty property for array` but I know the data is being sent to the backend.

php controller:

```
public function formatLive(Request $request)
{
 $this->formatData($request->copy_urls);
}

public function formatData($url)
{
   //empty
}
```

Comment: @linktoahref still getting same `Cannot access empty property`

Comment: What property are you trying to access ?

Comment: @linktoahref $request->copy_urls

Comment: provide route ,controller method as well as js script full code so that atleast someone help you easily

Comment: read docs ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-json-input-values
try with $request->input('copy_urls')

Comment: @Svetoslav no, that was something I tried before even making the ticket here.  No luck

Comment: what do you receive on $request->all() ?

Comment: @Svetoslav I did `dd($request->all())` and it's an array of properties.  `copy_urls` is an array as well within with the data

Comment: here I think the issue is with _ to camilCase $request->copyUrls

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the property of the object in quotes.

```
[
    {
        target: "page:455880961418394",
        stream_url: "fds",
        stream_key: "sdf"
    },
    {
        target: "page:f334234",
        stream_url: "test",
        stream_key: "test1"
    }
]
```

Doing `json_decode` on the above data, it returns null. The above JSON
is NOT valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specification).

```
json_decode($json_data, true); // null
```

After wrapping the properties with quotes,

```
[
    {
        "target": "page:455880961418394",
        "stream_url": "fds",
        "stream_key": "sdf"
    },
    {
        "target": "page:f334234",
        "stream_url": "test",
        "stream_key": "test1"
    }
]
```

Doing `json_decode` on the above data returns the array

```
$some_variable = json_decode($json_data, true);
```

Returns,

```
[
     [
       "target" => "page:455880961418394",
       "stream_url" => "fds",
       "stream_key" => "sdf",
     ],
     [
       "target" => "page:f334234",
       "stream_url" => "test",
       "stream_key" => "test1",
     ],
]
```

See Example #3 in [Documentation](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

Comment: still same.  I changed to valid JSON and then accessed it like this:
`$this->formatData(json_encode($request->copy_urls, true));`

Comment: @ddjk Please share your controller code corresponding to the route `admin/finish-live`

Comment: added to the original above √

Comment: @ddjk Your controller code seems fine, just for the sake of debugging, have you imported the Request class?

Comment: yep Request is imported